# ColumnToggle: hide some columns

Tags: primefaces

I'm working with primefaces 5.0 and i created one Primefaces:Datatable with Column:ColumnToggle but i need define initial columns to display.
How to hide some columns initially?
With property toggleable="false" i define that column not toggleable. Don't exist one property that defines initial columns?

```
<p:datatable ...>
    <f:facet name="header">
          <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Data" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
          <p:columnToggler datasource="itemsDT" trigger="toggler" />
    </f:facet>
    ...
</p:datatable>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25487243/3703397

Answer (score 1):

> How to hide some columns initially?

use `visible="false"`.

Example

```
<p:column filterBy="#{vo.faxNo}" headerText="Fax No." sortBy="#{vo.faxNo}"
                    filterStyle="width: 90%" style="width: 130px;" visible="false" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{vo.faxNo}" />
                </p:column>
```

Comment: Better to vote for the question being a duplicate of the link in the comment. Now we get to 'similar' Q/A entries