# Primefaces initialize columnToggler

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I use following example from primefaces...

[columnToggler-Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columnToggler.xhtml)

Is there a possibility to preselect / initilize the columns in the Bean? I want to load just specific columns [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqebS.png). The View will have about 30 Columns and the user should be able to customize different views that can be saved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I initially hide columns in a p:dataTable with p:columnToggler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487243/how-can-i-initially-hide-columns-in-a-pdatatable-with-pcolumntoggler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach this the wrong way. You can set the `visible` attribute per column and the columnToggler client-side takes a look at the resulting html for determining its state.

```
<p:column visible="#{visibilityModel.column(3)}" />
```

or by column name or whatever... Its up to you

See also

- http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3341

Comment: I know, but just found out it is a duplicate ;-) And taking a look in the docs might have given you hints

Comment: Yes, indeed. It was simply to easy :D, THX again.